# Any number in css

Tags: css

Here's the default code:

```
div.sidebar.fl aside#nav_menu-2.widget.widget_nav_menu { }
```

I try to style it with any number in nav_menu-*

I use something like this:

```
div.sidebar.fl aside#[id^="nav_menu"].widget.widget_nav_menu { }
```

It doesn't work. Where do I make a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

`aside#[id^="nav_menu"]`

Remove that `#`

The css should be

```
div.sidebar.fl aside[id^="nav_menu"].widget.widget_nav_menu { }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small mistake and I fixed it.

```css
div.sidebar.fl aside#nav_menu-2.widget.widget_nav_menu { 
  color : green;
}

div.sidebar.fl aside[id^="nav_menu"].widget.widget_nav_menu {
  color : Blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar fl">
  <aside id="nav_menu-1" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    Nav Menu1
  </aside>
  <aside id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    Nav Menu2
  </aside>
  <aside id="nav_menu-3" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    Nav Menu3
  </aside>
  <aside id="nav_menu-3" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    Nav Menu4
  </aside>
</div>
```

Oopsy!